# Passar dados para uma janela modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Não estou conseguindo passar os dados de uma tabela que tenho em uma página .php para uma janela modal que mostre esses dados, que seria para edição.

A única coisa que consigo passar é o id, que por sua vez consegue ser utilizado para realizar o update no banco de dados sem problemas caso eu preencha os inputs.

Gostaria de saber como posso passar esses dados da tabela para os input texts por JavaScript, ou por outro meio se possível.

Trigger para abrir a modal:

```
<i class="fas fa-edit ml-1" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCliente" id="btnEditar" onclick="editar(<?= $cliente->id ?>)"></i>
```

Inputs da janela modal:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="nomeCliente">Nome do Cliente</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nomeCliente" name="nomeCliente">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="cpfCliente">CPF</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cpfCliente" name="cpfCliente" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="cnpjCliente">CNPJ</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cnpjCliente" name="cnpjCliente" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCNPJ );">
</div>
```

Tabela que lista os dados:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" id="tabelaClientes">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>CNPJ</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Opções</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <? foreach ($listaCliente as $indice => $cliente) { ?>

        <tr><td>
                <?= $cliente->nome ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?= $cliente->cpf ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?= $cliente->cnpj?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?= $cliente->id ?>
            </td>

            <td class="opcoes">

                <i class="fas fa-edit ml-1" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCliente" id="btnEditar" onclick="editar(<?= $cliente->id ?>)"></i>

                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-1" title="Excluir" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExcluir" ></i>

            </td>

        </tr>

    <? } ?>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos inputs da modal você não informou onde quer passar o id, mas uma forma de preencher os inputs da modal é alterar a forma de chamar a função `editar`. Primeiro altere o onclick para:

```
onclick="editar(this)"
```

O `this` como argumento representa o elemento clicado. Assim fica fácil de pegar os dados da respectiva linha.

E a função `editar` ficaria assim para pegar os valores das colunas:

```
function editar(e){

   var linha = $(e).closest("tr");
   var nome = linha.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim(); // texto da primeira coluna
   var cpf  = linha.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim(); // texto da segunda coluna
   var cnpj = linha.find("td:eq(2)").text().trim(); // texto da terceira coluna
   var id   = linha.find("td:eq(3)").text().trim(); // texto da quarta coluna

   $("#nomeCliente").val(nome);
   $("#cpfCliente").val(cpf);
   $("#cnpjCliente").val(cnpj);

}
```

**Veja:**

```js
function editar(e){

   var linha = $(e).closest("tr");
   var nome = linha.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim(); // texto da primeira coluna
   var cpf  = linha.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim(); // texto da segunda coluna
   var cnpj = linha.find("td:eq(2)").text().trim(); // texto da terceira coluna
   var id   = linha.find("td:eq(3)").text().trim(); // texto da quarta coluna

   $("#nomeCliente").val(nome);
   $("#cpfCliente").val(cpf);
   $("#cnpjCliente").val(cnpj);
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" id="tabelaClientes">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>CNPJ</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Opções</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

        <tr><td>
                Fulano
            </td>

            <td>
                cpf123
            </td>

            <td>
                cnpj123
            </td>

            <td>
                1
            </td>

            <td class="opcoes">

                <i class="fas fa-edit ml-1" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCliente" class="btnEditar" onclick="editar(this)"></i>

                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-1" title="Excluir" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExcluir" ></i>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr><td>
                Ciclano
            </td>

            <td>
                cpf456
            </td>

            <td>
                cnpj456
            </td>

            <td>
                2
            </td>

            <td class="opcoes">

                <i class="fas fa-edit ml-1" title="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCliente" class="btnEditar" onclick="editar(this)"></i>

                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt ml-1" title="Excluir" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExcluir" ></i>

            </td>

        </tr>


</tbody>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <div class="col-md-6">
             <label for="nomeCliente">Nome do Cliente</label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nomeCliente" name="nomeCliente">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <label for="cpfCliente">CPF</label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cpfCliente" name="cpfCliente" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <label for="cnpjCliente">CNPJ</label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cnpjCliente" name="cnpjCliente" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCNPJ );">
         </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria, o problema acima foi resolvido apenas com isso, que estava quebrando minha cabeça. Agora outro "problema" que surge, é que os dados da table não são todos os que existem na tabela cliente do BD, existem outros atributos como email, telefone, etc. Para isso, eu consigo utilizar da função editar() para acessar o BD e resgatar os esses dados, através do ID ?

Comment: Sim, aí vc teria que usar Ajax.